# Entity model won't refresh in code after a change

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an entity model (EF4) in Lazy mode and I'm updating/presenting it through a windows form . the database can also be updated from stored procedures by a different application.

I'm calling to the Refresh method with RefreshMode.StoreWins + the object that was changed but I don't see any change. In fact, with an sql profiler on, I don't see any DB access after the refresh.

Thanks
Avi